# Is any subring of a field which contains the identity is itself a subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Prove that or give counterexample(s):

> Any subring of a field which contains the identity is a subfield

Answer (score 10):

$\mathbb{Z}$ inside $\mathbb{Q}$  is a subring with identity which is not a subfield. , Note that non zero field element is a group under multiplication. So it is not just enough to have identity alone.

Answer (score 10):

If $R$ is a *finite* subring of a field $F$, then it is a subfield. This follows from the fact that a finite submonoid of a group is a subgroup. Let $r\in R$, $r\ne 0$ and consider the map $f\colon R\to R$ given by $f(x)=rx$. This is injective because $R$ is a domain, hence also surjective because $R$ is finite; since $1\in R$, you find $x\in R$ with $rx=1$.

Actually this is a general fact: every finite domain is a field, the argument is exactly the same.

For infinite $R$ this isn't true, as shown in other answers.

Comment: nice explanation giving general context!

Answer (score 5):

consider $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}$, all your conditions hold but $\mathbb{Z}$ isnt a field.

Comment: I am 20 sec faster than you :) , nice example

Comment: It's too early, hehe :)

Comment: So a subring of a Field need not be a subield. Am i right?